# What parameters are best for a Decision Tree in Rapidminer

Tags: statistics, decision-tree, data-analysis, rapidminer

I have a set of data with 14 regular attributes. I am trying to create the best decison tree in **rapidminer** from this training data so that I can use this tree on scoring data.

However I am not sure what paramaters to use for the decision tree (eg: criterion, minimal gain, confidence, etc)? 
I am also unsure of which (if at all) other operators I could/should apply to my model?

Could anyone provide me with some general tips about what would work best?

The data I have is to try and determine whether someone opening a new bank account, will they have a good credit standing. I have information such as Credit standing, account type, history, employment, gender, job, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the number of samples will help the machine learning process better. please refer to this link this might be of some help to you http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/55751/how-to-use-decision-trees-for-credit-scoring-using-rapidminer-part-1

Comment: I had a read of that already but it doesnt quite explain why you would choose certain values for the data you get provided. Thats where I need some explanations?

Comment: Are you asking which attributes to choose and why? or What are the various input parameters we give to the model and why ? Can you please clarify. Thanks.